# Error al desplegar Funcion para Firestore

Tags: function, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-messaging

Actualmente estoy viendo cual puede ser el error que estoy cometiendo al ejecutar esta función, lo que busco es que cada vez que en la subcollection 'mensajes' se cree un nuevo documento se dispare una notificación al receptor obteniendo su token FCM previamente.

Subcolleccion mensajes:
**Chats**->**docid**-> **mensajes**-> **mjeid**->
**campos** : "mensaje","parauid","perfil","usuario",

Collection usuarios:
**Usuarios**-> **docuid**-> campo 'token'

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.enviarNotificacion  = functions.firestore.document('Chats/{docId}/mensajes/{mensajeId}').onCreate((snap, context)=>{
const  mje = snap.get('mensaje');
const  puid = snap.get('parauid')
const  dperfil = snap.get('perfil')
const  dusuario = snap.get('usuario')
const  doc = await admin.firestore().collection('Usuarios').doc(puid).get();
const token = doc.get('token');
    var mensaje = {
            notification : {
               title = dusuario,
                body = msje,
                imageUrl = dperfil,
            },token: token,
        }
   const response = await admin.messaging().send(mensaje);
   console.log(response);
});
```

El error que recibo es el siguiente :

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

C:\Users\Santiago\Desktop\LopeerHS\firebase\functions\index.js:10

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:19:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:57:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

¿Cuál seria el error de la línea 10? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son errores de sintaxis:

- estás usando `=` en vez de `:` para darle valor a las propiedades del objeto `notification`
- creas una variable llamada "mje" pero cuando quieres usarla escribes "msje"
- intentas usar `await` sin haber marcado la función como `async`

Así debería quedar:

```
exports.enviarNotificacion = functions.firestore.document('Chats/{docId}/mensajes/{mensajeId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const puid = snap.get('parauid')
    const doc = await admin.firestore().collection('Usuarios').doc(puid).get();
    const mensaje = {
        notification: {
            title: snap.get('usuario'),
            body: snap.get('mensaje'),
            imageUrl: snap.get('perfil'),
        },
        token: doc.get('token'),
    }
    return admin.messaging().send(mensaje);
});
```